# How can I profile how much memory GHC is using to compile my project using Stack?

Tags: haskell, memory, profiling, ghc, haskell-stack

I have a Haskell library built using Stack and I'm trying to see how much memory is used to compile it. What arguments do I pass on the command line to see memory usage during compilation?

I know I need some mix of `+RTS`, `-RTS`, and `-s`, but I always get them mixed up.

Comment: This works for me: `stack build --ghc-options='-j +RTS -s -RTS'`

Comment: @Sibi that fails for me with `ghc: unrecognised flag: -s`

Comment: Ah got it, I had left some flags in the `package.yaml` file that was causing that error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
stack build --ghc-options='-j +RTS -s -RTS'
```